# Media resources not found on GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, github-pages, media

I am trying to upload a React project, created with create-react-app, to github pages. After running `npm run build`, I uploaded the built content to github, but nothing was found. I fixed a missing `./` both in *index.html* (by adding `<base href="./" />`) anc in *asset-manifest.json* (all entries were like `"main.js": "/static/js/main.238dbb45.js"` and I changed them manually to `"main.js": "./static/js/main.238dbb45.js"`). I also added `"start_url": "https://ilDeffo.github.io/MyProject/"` to my manifest.json
Before this change, the error I had in the browser console was *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()* and the resource urls were all like */static/js/main.238dbb45.js*.

This little change fixed almost everything, except for the media files: the error message is the same as before, but now the urls of media files (.png, .jpg) are like *"https://ilDeffo.github.io/static/media/my_image.png"* so it looks like */MyProject/* is missing in this url.

What am I missing?

My Files:
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <base href="./" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta
            name="description"
            content="Web site created using create-react-app"
        />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
        <title>MyProject</title>
        <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.238dbb45.js"></script>
        <link href="/static/css/main.23037022.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "short_name": "MyProject",
    "name": "MyProject",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "favicon.ico",
            "sizes": "64x64 32x32 16x16",
            "type": "image/x-icon"
        },
        {
            "src": "logo192.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "192x192"
        },
        {
            "src": "logo512.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "512x512"
        }
    ],
    "start_url": "https://ilDeffo.github.io/MyProject/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "theme_color": "#000000",
    "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

**assets-manifest.json**

```
{
  "files": {
    "main.css": "./static/css/main.23037022.css",
    "main.js": "./static/js/main.238dbb45.js",
    "static/js/453.d7c8ad91.chunk.js": "./static/js/453.d7c8ad91.chunk.js",
    "static/media/my_image.jpg": "./static/media/my_image.3b164cd332d9eaf73dd0.jpg",
    "static/media/my_image2.png": "./static/media/my_image2.95a63c7274aa5a772bd0.png",
    "index.html": "./index.html",
    "main.23037022.css.map": "./static/css/main.23037022.css.map",
    "main.238dbb45.js.map": "./static/js/main.238dbb45.js.map",
    "453.d7c8ad91.chunk.js.map": "./static/js/453.d7c8ad91.chunk.js.map"
  },
  "entrypoints": [
    "./static/css/main.23037022.css",
    "./static/js/main.238dbb45.js"
  ]
}
```

Please feel free to ask for any additional info or piece of code.

Thanks.

***EDIT***
Folder structure is teh following:

```
MyProject
|
|__ public
|   |
|   |_ favicon.ico    
|   |_ index.html 
|   |_ logo192.png
|   |_ logo512.png
|   |_ manifest.json
|   |_ robots.txt
|
|__src
|   |_ assets
|   |  |
|   |  |_my_image.png
|   |  |_my_image2.png
|   |
|   |_ css
|   |  |
|   |  |_index.css
|   |
|   |_ App.js
|   |_ index.js
|
|_ package.json
```

Comment: Hi! If your having an issue with Github Pages, linking the repository directory structure is important. That way, we have the relevant information to understand the issue your facing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that adding

```
"homepage": "https://ilDeffo.github.io/MyProject/"
```

fixed the problem